# Define a custom content type for a Folder inside a document library will be ignored when creating a folder using One Drive inside my PC

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, custom-content-type

I have created a custom content type name Foldercustom which have its parent = Folder and contain a custom column named "Dept", as follow:-

[image]

now inside the document library i defined the FolderCustom content type as the default content type, as follow:-

[image: thumbnail image 2 of blog post titled]

But when I sync the library using one drive and I create a new folder inside my PC >> the folder created inside the document library will still have the built-in Folder content type instead of the Foldercustom content type. is this a bug   ??

Answer (score 1):

The custom content type only can be used in the SharePoint Online.

It's by design, in the local pc, users could only create default folders.

Comment: unfortunatly this is the case, while content types for files seems to work well when creating the files from local PC.. i think this is a debug that Microsoft should solve... what do you think?